# Is it possible to switch Transform Orientation from Global to Normal on the fly with just mousewheel?

Tags: workflow

I favor the mousewheel gesture to lock axes instead of pressing the axis letter on the keyboard. I'd like to know if you can do an equivalent to X,X or Z,Z to change the axis of an active transformation to Normal with just the mousewheel. I was sure I managed to do it at some point but I can't seem to find out how.

Comment: The Pie menus all have a quick-swipe gesture..(no button) is that how you did it?

Comment: No. That's on colon key or something, right? I was sure I just pressed a modifier + mousewheel click. I must be mistaken and probably remember wrong or something. Is it not possible to do the equivalent to X,X with just the mouse wheel? :(

Comment: Someone may come up with it.. it would be nice..